# ubuntu 14.04 wireless not working on Macbook pro dual boot

Tags: 14.04, networking, drivers, wireless, macbook

I have installed Ubuntu 14.04 on Macbook pro 13.3.
The wifi was working perfectly fine and has stopped working now.

I have tried the below solutions:

```
sudo apt-get install dkms bcmwl-kernel-source
sudo modprobe wl
```

It gets stuck on `sudo modprobe wl`

My output for `sudo lshw -C Network` is below:

```
*-network               
       description: Network controller
       product: BCM43602 802.11ac Wireless LAN SoC
       vendor: Broadcom Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       version: 01
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
       configuration: driver=wl latency=0
       resources: irq:18 memory:c1400000-c1407fff memory:c1000000-c13fffff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 2
       bus info: usb@1:1
       logical name: eth0
       serial: 0e:51:01:26:f1:eb
       capabilities: ethernet physical
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=ipheth ip=172.20.10.4 link=yes multicast=yes
```

output for `lspci -nn | grep 0280 is`:

```
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM43602 802.11ac Wireless LAN SoC [14e4:43ba] (rev 01)
```

When I tried `sudo apt-get install --reinstall bcmwl-kernel-source`:

it got stuck at:

```
Setting up bcmwl-kernel-source (6.30.223.248+bdcom-0ubuntu0.2) ...
Removing old bcmwl-6.30.223.248+bdcom DKMS files...

-------- Uninstall Beginning --------
Module:  bcmwl
Version: 6.30.223.248+bdcom
Kernel:  4.4.0-62-generic (x86_64)
-------------------------------------

Status: Before uninstall, this module version was ACTIVE on this kernel.

wl.ko:
 - Uninstallation
   - Deleting from: /lib/modules/4.4.0-62-generic/updates/dkms/
 - Original module
   - No original module was found for this module on this kernel.
   - Use the dkms install command to reinstall any previous module version.

depmod....

DKMS: uninstall completed.

------------------------------
Deleting module version: 6.30.223.248+bdcom
completely from the DKMS tree.
------------------------------
Done.
Loading new bcmwl-6.30.223.248+bdcom DKMS files...
Building only for 4.4.0-62-generic
Building for architecture x86_64
Building initial module for 4.4.0-62-generic
Done.

wl:
Running module version sanity check.
 - Original module
   - No original module exists within this kernel
 - Installation
   - Installing to /lib/modules/4.4.0-62-generic/updates/dkms/

depmod....

DKMS: install completed.
```

so I killed it and tried `sudo apt-get update` and got the error:

I got the error :

```
E: dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a' to correct the problem.
```

When I tried `sudo dpkg --configure -a` :

it gets stuck like below:

```
Setting up bcmwl-kernel-source (6.30.223.248+bdcom-0ubuntu0.2) ...
Removing old bcmwl-6.30.223.248+bdcom DKMS files...

-------- Uninstall Beginning --------
Module:  bcmwl
Version: 6.30.223.248+bdcom
Kernel:  4.4.0-62-generic (x86_64)
-------------------------------------

Status: Before uninstall, this module version was ACTIVE on this kernel.

wl.ko:
 - Uninstallation
   - Deleting from: /lib/modules/4.4.0-62-generic/updates/dkms/
 - Original module
   - No original module was found for this module on this kernel.
   - Use the dkms install command to reinstall any previous module version.

depmod....

DKMS: uninstall completed.

------------------------------
Deleting module version: 6.30.223.248+bdcom
completely from the DKMS tree.
------------------------------
Done.
Loading new bcmwl-6.30.223.248+bdcom DKMS files...
Building only for 4.4.0-62-generic
Building for architecture x86_64
Building initial module for 4.4.0-62-generic
Done.

wl:
Running module version sanity check.
 - Original module
   - No original module exists within this kernel
 - Installation
   - Installing to /lib/modules/4.4.0-62-generic/updates/dkms/

depmod....

DKMS: install completed.
```

I am not sure what to try now.
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Does it work with the other OS?

Comment: Yes the wifi works with on MacOS Sierra

Comment: `bcmwl-kernel-source` is a wrong driver. Uninstall it.

Comment: @Pilot6 it worked. Thank you so much. Can you add it as the answer instead of a comment. I'll close the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `bcmwl-kernel-source` is a wrong driver for this `Broadcom Corporation BCM43602 802.11ac Wireless LAN SoC [14e4:43ba] (rev 01)` adapter. It will not work with it.

The proper driver is `brcmfmac`. It is built in the kernel.

Uninstall the `wl` by

```
sudo apt purge bcmwl-kernel-source
```

and the Wi-Fi should work.